# dplyr count single observations in list of tibbles using purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to count the frequency of occurrences in a list of tibbles containing individual observations separated by ";". I am running into an error when I use a `purrr::map()` within `purrr::map()`. I suspect that I am missing something simple so any help is appreciated.

Take an example input of fruit purchases from different customers where fruits purchased at the same time are separated by ";"

```
# Fruit purchases across days with different number of customers.
day_1 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("oranges;peaches;apples", "pears;apples", "bananas", "oranges;apples", "apples")), "fruits"))
day_2 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("oranges;apples", "peaches","apples;bananas;", "pears", "apples;peaches", "oranges")), "fruits"))
day_3 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("peaches;pears","apples","bananas")), "fruits"))

# Create list of fruit purchases.
fruit_list <- list(day_1, day_2, day_3)
```

This returns a list of three tibbles and is the general format of my data. I am able to count the number of total observations for each fruit per day by using `dplyr`/`purrr`:

```
fruit_list %>% 
  map(function(x) strsplit(x$fruits, ";")) %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  map(table)
```

However, when I attempt to isolate and tally the single fruit purchases across the list of tibbles using a `map()` within a `map()` I run into the error

> "Error: `.x` is not a vector (closure)"

```
fruit_list %>% 
  map(mutate(fruit_count = map(function(x) strsplit(x$fruits, ";"), length))) %>% 
  filter(fruit_count==1) %>% 
  count(solo_fruits = fruits)
```

I can perform this function on a single tibble/df, but not across the list of tibbles. Am I missing something with the `map()` function or something more obvious? Thanks!

### Desired result format for first tibble:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  solo_fruits     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 apples          1
2 bananas         1
```

How I derived the above answer for single sample:

```
day_1_df <- as.data.frame(fruit_list[[1]]) 
day_1_df %>% 
  mutate(fruit_count = map(strsplit(day_1_df$fruits, ";"), length)) %>% 
  filter(fruit_count==1) %>% 
  count(solo_fruits = fruits)
```

Comment: Probably better if you have one larger tibble rather than a list of tibbles. Any reason you're doing the latter?

Comment: Good point, there's no reason not to have a larger tibble. Your suggestion below provided the right framework to solve my issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but it might solve your problem in a different way:

```
library(tidyverse)

day_1 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("oranges;peaches;apples", "pears;apples", "bananas", "oranges;apples", "apples")), "fruits"))
day_2 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("oranges;apples", "peaches","apples;bananas;", "pears", "apples;peaches", "oranges")), "fruits"))
day_3 <- as_data_frame(setNames(list(c("peaches;pears","apples","bananas")), "fruits"))

df <- tibble(day = 1:3, fruits = c(day_1, day_2, day_3)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(fruits = strsplit(fruits, ";"), customer = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest()

df %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  group_by(customer, day, fruits) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# # Groups:   customer, day [?]
#   customer   day fruits      n
#      <int> <int> <chr>   <int>
# 1        3     1 bananas     1
# 2        5     1 apples      1
# 3        7     2 peaches     1
# 4        9     2 pears       1
# 5       11     2 oranges     1
# 6       13     3 apples      1
# 7       14     3 bananas     1
```

Edit: Changed after misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_detect` just to capture the lines that have no `;`. or you can use str_count to count `;` then add 1.

```
fruit_list%>%
     map(~filter(.x,!str_detect(fruits,";"))%>%
             mutate(solo_fruits = fruits,count = 1,fruits=NULL))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  solo_fruits count
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 bananas         1
2 apples          1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  solo_fruits count
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 peaches         1
2 pears           1
3 oranges         1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  solo_fruits count
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 apples          1
2 bananas         1
```

what I mean by using `str_count`: which will give you the total number of fruits per row. instead of splitting and then using length

```
fruit_list%>%
    map(~mutate(.x,count = str_count(fruits,";") + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It worked in this particular case.